# How to get field corresponding to result of a function in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to extract a field that corresponds to the result of a function in elasticsearch. e.g. give me the field 'elaspsedTime' of the record that has the maximum timestamp.  I would ideally like to do this as part of an "aggs" clause

```
...
"aggs": {
    "minStart": {
        "min": {
            "field": "@timestamp"
        }
    },
   "maxStop": {
        "max": {
            "field": "@timestamp"
        }
    },
    "elapsedTimeForMax" : {
        // field 'elaspedTime' corresponding the 'max' field
    }
    ...
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to use a `top_hits` aggregation, like this:

```
"aggs": {
    "minStart": {
        "min": {
            "field": "@timestamp"
        }
    },
    "maxStop": {
        "max": {
            "field": "@timestamp"
        }
    },
    "elapsedTimeForMax" : {
        "top_hits": {
           "sort": {"@timestamp": "desc"},
           "size": 1,
           "_source": ["elapsedTime"]
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Well if you have a min and max aggregation on `@timestamp` the field must exist of course. I assumed it was the case

Comment: Can you run this and update your question with the results ? `curl -XGET localhost:9200/jmeter_perf_results `

Comment: Your answer is correct.  Problem was between the chair and the keyboard.  My indexes are of the form jmeter_perf_results-<date> and I was picking up some older data from an index called jmeter_perf_results i.e. without the date.  This was throwing some shard exceptions.  When I changed the index for the query to be "jmeter_perf_result-*" instead of "jmeter_perf_result*" it worked fine.  Thanks again.